# How to handle exceptions in a Django database setting?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-settings, django-database

I have a Django application which gives the operational error:

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on '172.16.1.38' (111)")
```

When I am giving the wrong port number or IP address in database configuration of setting.py file.
For example:

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
    'NAME': "movement",
    'HOST': "172.16.1.38",
    'PORT': 3306,
    'USER': "adc",
    'PASSWORD': "abcde",
    }
}
```

above is the correct configuration of the database access but if I mess with any of the value from PORT, HOST or USER, I am getting the operation error.
So, I wanted to know, is there any way to show a message instead of this error? or how can I handle this exception?

Comment: Well you are not supposed to give wrong details.

Comment: @SandeepBalagopal yes, I agree! but in case if it happens then do we have any way to handle it ?

Comment: It is being handled; it's showing an exception .What else would you like to happen?

Comment: @DanielRoseman I just wanted to do is when this exception occurs then instead of showing this lengthy error message it shows an appropriate one or two line message, i.e is it possible to catch this error somewhere and throw a message? I don't know whether it is possible or not.

Comment: You can write a middleware and catch this exception when a request is made to your site. Then you could display some user-friendly message like: "Database connection is down, please try later.". Is that what you intend?

Comment: @cezar yes, this is what I want, so can you write an example for the same?